# How to switch to editing command in text editor

Tags: bash, command-line, vim

When typing a complicated command that started on the command line in Bash, how do I switch to editing it with ViM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a readline command, called `edit-and-execute-command` tied to the sequence <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, that invokes your editor with the current content of the command line for editing.

When you exit the editor the command is executed.

Comment: Should also add that the editor that is used can be set in the EDITOR environment variable.  I added this to my bashrc: "export EDITOR="$(which vim )"

Comment: Whoa... that's just cool. I learned something today!

Comment: For those that use `set -o vi`, you want to hit `Esc` `v`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do so in the middle of typing in the command, but you (at least in my experience) can switch to an 'emacs' or a 'vi' line-editing mode via `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi` respectively. Those commands will set keybindings for things like last-command, erase-word, erase-to-end-of-line, erase-to-start-of-line, etc.

Comment: `emacs` is the default in `readline`.